# Python3.5 and Eclipse error with pywin32

Tags: python

ive got a really annoying error , when i import a module in Eclipse 
i get always that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\b_origin\workspace\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've installed pywin32 , their folders are in C:\Users\b_origin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\ but always i get that error.
When i run python from CMD , they are being imported correctly with no errors.
Check the picture belove to see my preferences/interpreter in Eclipse 
[my preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVvbF.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490233/win32com-import-error-python-3-4

Comment: After copied pywintypes35.dll and pythoncom35.dll into win32 folder it WORKED ! Thanks !!!!!!!!